# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'select fno from apts where name like '%jagd%'' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I write a stored procedure as follows

```
IF @Action=101  
BEGIN 

select  a.name as Name,
        m.sccity as sccity, 
        ISNULL(c.coursetype,' ')+': '+ISNULL(c.coursename,'')+', CODE:'+Convert(varchar(4),c.course) as 'Course Details',
        replace(convert(varchar(20),a.dob,106),' ','-') as dob,
        a.gender as gender,
        a.medium as medium,
        a.cat as cat,
        a.oldfno as oldfno,
        a.bgroup as bgroup,
        a.add1 as add1,
        a.add2 as add2,
        a.add3 as add3,
        a.city as city,
        a.district as district,
        a.state as state,
        a.pin as pin,
        a.std as std,
        a.phone1 as phone1,
        a.phone2 as phone2,
        a.mobile1 as mobile1,
        a.mobile2 as mobile2,
        a.pcourse as pcourse  
from apts a, courses c ,mastsc m 
where c.course=a.course   
and a.studyccode=m.studyccode 
and a.isdeleted=0 and c.isdeleted=0 
and m.isdeleted=0 and c.course>0 
and a.fno in (@subquery)

END
```

There is two variable @Action type integer and @subquery type varchar 
@subquery is passed in  IN() clause .But when I executing this and pass a subquery I get an error. Please provide a solution .Thanks in advance

Comment: a.fno in ( cast(@subquery as int)) END

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a.fno in ( cast(@subquery as int)) END
```

Comment: no its not working .same error                                                                         Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'select fno from apts where mobile1 like %ajay%' to data type int.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic SQL here.

Put you select query into some variable like:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
--here comes your query
and a.fno in ('+@subquery+')'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

But this method is extremely vulnerable for SQL injections, better use some other logic for delivering sub-query to your SP. For example:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
--here comes your query
and a.fno in (SELECT fno FROM apts WHERE mobile1 like ''%'+@stringtosearch+'%'')'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```